# How to write IF SELECT without using the into

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, if-statement

I want to execute this statement

```
if (select object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'xxx')='PROGRAM' then .......
```

But the problem is that i can't make such statement without using varible like :

```
select object_type into ala from user_objects where object_name = 'xxx';
  if ala !='PROGRAM' then ...
```

Do you have any idea how can i perform the first statement without using the INTO with variable ?

Thank you!

Comment: Postgres or Oracle? That makes quite a difference. But in neither can you use `IF` in SQL, only in PL/SQL or PL/pgSQL

Comment: **a)** What's wrong with INTO? I mean, for what reason would you want to avoid it? **b)** What comes after THEN? The answer might depend on that.

Comment: i want the minimum number of variable and with the into i must use a variable !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the workaround of using a for loop in oracle with the same effect if there is more than one `object_type <> PROGRAM`.

```
 for rec in (select object_type from user_objects where 
 object_name = 'xxx' and object_type<>'PROGRAM')
 loop
 <statements goes here> 
 end loop;
```